# Hapijs running test ignoring the leaks

Tags: hapi.js

I am building a web application using [HapiJS](https://hapi.dev/). I am writing tests for my application. I am running the test using the following command:

```
lab -v test/**/*.test.js
```

When I run the tests I am getting the following error even though all the tests pass:

```
The following leaks were detected:__extends, __assign, __rest, __decorate, __param, __metadata, __awaiter, __generator, __exportStar, __createBinding, __values, __read, __spread, __spreadArrays, __spreadArray, __await, __asyncGenerator, __asyncDelegator, __asyncValues, __makeTemplateObject, __importStar, __importDefault, __classPrivateFieldGet, __classPrivateFieldSet
```

I am trying to ignore that using the following commands:

```
lab -v --globals test/**/*.test.js

lab -v -I test/**/*.test.js

lab -v --ignore test/**/*.test.js
```

But none of the commands above are working. How can I ignore that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`doc`](https://hapi.dev/module/lab/api/?v=24.6.0#command-line)

> `-l`, `--leaks` - disables global variable leak detection.

Or

> `-I`, `--ignore` - ignore a list of globals for the leak detection (comma separated), this is an alias of globals property in .labrc file. To ignore symbols, pass the symbol's string representation (e.g. Symbol(special)).

**.labrc.js** Example

```
module.exports = {
    globals: ['__extends', '__assign', '__rest', ...],
};
```

You can check the example [`HERE`](https://github.com/hapijs/lab/tree/14d4d6b0dbc40528e7e83e57418bd2c1b96e022a/test/cli_labrc)